# .Net Core 2.1 Web and Console DbContexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Im not known for my clarity when asking questions, so forgive me, also i have no formal training for any of this but im stumped.

I am mid upgrade from .Net 4.7.1 to .Net Core 2.1, my solution consists of 2 parts, an IIS Web Application for MVC, and a Console Application, the IIS App displays data, and the console application does all the actual processing.

Before i started this port for my console app when i needed stuff from the database i would simply

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    SomethingModel model = db.X.First(x => x.Whatever == whatever);
}
```

And just like that i have the data i want from the database, butttt do you think i can do that with Core 2.1 can i hell.

I got all the code ported all the refrences resolved and so far as i can tell its ready to run. Except i cant call data from the database and im stumped, google just shows code first and ef stuff, or i dont know what im really asking.

So if anyone can help its much appreciated

-- Update 1---

The error is An Object refrence is required for the non-static field, metho or property Program._db

The DbModel is defined in Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs for the IIS App and is as follows

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>
options)
            : base(options)
         {
         }
```

-- Program.cs for Console App

```
 class Program
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _db { get; }
        public Program(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _db = context;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new ExecutionEngine(_db).Run();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is happening? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: So Core has a different configuration model. You should at least post where you configure the context, and the constructor. Real pretty would be to use the DI but that may be too much for an existing app.

Comment: I have updated the origonal question hopefully for some clarity

Comment: Its not an **upgrade**. ASP.NET Core MVC  is not a new version of ASP.NET MVC, its a completely newly written framework. You can only **migrate** to ASP.NET Core, not upgrade to it. Its not as easy as changing a handful of packages and expect it to work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The previous way you wrote the code (`using`) was *never* a good idea. Your context should be request-scoped; using `using` can lead to all sorts of issues with entity tracking and totally destroys all the helpful caching EF does. The best method for getting a context instance was always dependency injection via a DI container.

ASP.NET Core uses dependency injection for everything, and because of this EF Core's `DbContext` is *designed* to be dependency injected. In this regard, it no longer uses a default constructor out of the box, which is why your old code is failing (it depends on there being a default constructor).

Long and short, do things right and inject your context. It looks like you're *attempting* to do this based on your update. However, you cannot inject into something like `Program`. This is the entry point for your application, which means literally nothing exists yet. If you take a look at your web app, you'll notice that `Program` there sets up the web host builder (using `Startup`) and then builds and runs it. Behind the scenes this is doing a bunch of stuff, including setting up the service collection. This is what you need to do in your console app (set up the service collection). That's relatively straight forward:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(o =>
                o.UseSqlServer("connection string"))
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        var context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        new ExecutionEngine(context).Run();
    }
}
```

Now, this is a bit of overkill just based on the code you have here. You can simply new up an instance of your context via `DbContextOptionsBuilder`:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .UseSqlServer("connection string")
    .Options;
var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options);
```

However, using the service collection allows you to handle more advanced scenarios and better reuse your instances of things like your context across your codebase. Also it's worth mentioning that you should probably consider integrating configuration providers as well, so you don't need to hardcode your connection string. That's also relatively straight-forward:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory))
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
    .Build();
```

You might also want to add environment-specific configuration:

```
var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
```

Then:

```
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true);
```

This is just the same as doing all this in a web app, so you can add whatever type of configuration you like.

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for your detailed post i will give it a try and well learn i guess. My previous (using), the code in question is inherited and i just carried on with what they had done before, i have no training at all on devolopment of code, but im getting there slowly. I will report back with my findings.

Comment: Not to pick fault in your help but for others, can you change o.UseSqlServer("connection string")); to o.UseSqlServer("connection string"))
 the extra ;

Comment: Accepted answer for 3 reasons, 1 it does what i needed, 2 i learned something and 3, alot of other peaces just clicked together. Thank you Chris and the others :-)

Comment: @Mark: Good catch. Fixed.